# Archive Upload Failed due to error -22421

Tags: ios, itunes, xcode, archive

I was going to upload an app to iTunes Store, everything was going perfect, app validation test is also successfully completed, but when I tried to submit my app it gives an error.

Here a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Someone please can explain me the reason of this error and also to suggest me what to do.
Thanks.

Comment: I get this every now and then... If I wait a few minutes and retry, it works, so it seems to indicate some problem on Apple's servers.

Answer (score 1):

It's Apple's servers issues. You should try again and again...

Answer (score 0):

iPad Multitasking support requires all the orientations but your app does not, so you need to opt out of it, just add the UIRequiresFullScreen key to your Xcode project’s Info.plist file and apply the Boolean value YES.